# Kotlin How to create a list of classes that can be instantianted dynamically

Tags: list, kotlin

I would like to have a list of classes which could be instantiated later in the program.
Something like:

```
val someClasses = listOf(ClassA, ClassB, ...)
for (myClass in someClasses) {
    val myObject = myClass()
    myObject.doSomething()
}
```

Of course it doesn't work.
Is it possible to do something like this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a list of functions that create instances of said classes.

The simplest way to do it is to reference the *constructor* of those classes using the syntax `::ClassName`. So, applying this to your example, assuming those classes have no-arg constructors:

```kotlin
val someClassConstructors = listOf(::ClassA, ::ClassB, ...)
for (myConstructor in someClassConstructors) {
    val myObject = myConstructor()
    myObject.doSomething()
}
```

The above assumes that all your classes implement a common interface that has the `doSomething()` method.

Comment: Right, I updated the answer to make it more obvious